# What do these triple angle-brackets mean?

Tags: biblatex, abnt

I was looking at the contents of the `biblatex-abnt` package and noticed that their code is full of `% <<< 2` and `% >>> 2`

For instance, the file `doc/biblatex-abnt.tex` has:

```
\usepackage{parskip}% >>>2
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}% <<<2

\usepackage{titlesec}% >>>2
\newcommand{\subsectionbreak}{\clearpage}% <<<2
```

What do these (commented) angle brackets mean? Is this something idiosyncratic to this package (and author) or is this some convention?

Comment: conjecture (that file isn't quite the same as the one in tex live 2016): i'd interpret the lines `% >>>2` to mean that there's a second line that's important in relation to this line, and `% <<<2` to indicate that "this is the important second line".  in other words, they're pointers, not delimiters.

Comment: For the record, I got the package from [its CTAN page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-abnt).